# content: "" is working if is added in html style tag, but not in css file

Tags: css, twitter

Source : http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

To make the little black triangle for the drop down menus, Twitter is using the following CSS:

```
.caret 
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 4px solid black;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

I tried using `<b class="caret"></b>` but the color is gray. If you are on a Twitter Bootstrap page and remove the content: "" the triangle will be gray as well. If I add the code in HTML style tag

`<b style="-the code-"></b>` is black as it should be. Why is this happening ?

**Update**:

The code is the same but when it is in a CSS file the `opacity: 0.3`  is the one that makes the triangle gray, but still why this is not happening in the HTML style tag?

Comment: I suggest taking a second look at the alpha of the style. The triangle is black, but it appears gray because the alpha makes it very transparent.

Comment: The `b` tag is deprecated, you should use `strong` instead

Comment: @AlexW The `<b>` is not deprecated - it just has a different semantic meaning from `<strong>`

Comment: @ZoltanToth The `b` element should be used as a last resort when no other element is more appropriate. In particular, headings should use the `h1` to `h6` elements, stress emphasis should use the `em` element, importance should be denoted with the `strong` element, and text marked or highlighted should use the `mark` element. There are few practical cases where `b` is valid. Combine that information with the definition of deprecated: Express disapproval of.

Comment: @AlexW *"deprecation is a status applied to features, characteristics, or practices to indicate that they should be avoided, **typically because they have been superseded or not supported anymore.**"* Even if the `<b>` tag has a limited area of appropriate use it's still perfectly valid, supported and wasn't replaced by any new tag.

Comment: @ZoltanToth and `b` "should be avoided," in most cases. I suspect many people learning HTML are not aware of its correct use cases.

Comment: @AlexW Nope, it shouldn't :) http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/ As I said it *"has a limited area of appropriate use"* but has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't turn grey because you're including

```
content: "";
```

into

```
<b style="-the code-"></b>
```

and the double quotes are interfering. To fix it do

```
<b style="... content: ''; ..."></b>
```

That will work - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rS8JA/)